# Can you recommend a set theory book?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, book-recommendation

It should be about notion of sets, function, eq. rel. etc.

Comment: Enderton, [Elements of Set Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=JlR-Ehk35XkC&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: Goldrei, [Classic Set Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=1dLn0knvZSsC&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: Namely, I see baby set theory